# Trying to create a code that takes a string with specified length and outputs the integer value (ASCII)

Tags: c, ascii

The code skips the formula in the for loop and outputs a "-185" for every value of the string. I know there's a problem with the pointer declaration but I'm not sure how to fix it. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int d;
   int e=0; 
   int val; 
   printf("Enter the length of the string:\n");
   scanf("%d",&d);

   char *a = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char)*d);


   printf("Enter the string:\n");
   while(e<d)
   {
       scanf("%c",(a+e));
       e++;
   }

   printf("Outputed hash-code:\n");
   printf("-185 ");

   for(e = 0; e < d && *a; e++) {
      val = (int)*a;
      printf("%d ", ((val-96)*2 - 13));
   }

   printf("-185\n");
   return 0;

}
```

I am expecting an output like this

```
Enter the length of the string:
13
Enter the string:
hello world
Outputed hash-code:
-185 3 -3 11 11 17 -141 33 17 23 11 -5 -185
```

but I'm getting an output like this

```
Enter the length of the string:
13
Enter the string:
hello world
Outputed hash-code:
-185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185 -185
```

Comment: Please show some example input, and the expected *and* actual output from that input, and of course [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I also suggest you take some time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: What output are you expecting?

Comment: I have added examples of my outputs vs the expected outputs.

Comment: In the loop where you print the result, you use `*a` in the condition. It has the same problem as inside the loop, that you never modify `a` and it will always point to the same location. If you want to check for the string terminator you need to use `a[e]`. But that brings another problem, namely that you don't add a terminator to your string. Or that the check isn't needed since you already know the exact length of the input data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that, when printing your output, you do not increment `val` :

```
for (e = 0; e < d && *a; e++) {
    val = (int)*a;
    printf("%d ", ((val - 96) * 2 - 13));
}
```

I think you mean to add `e` to `a` when assigning to `val`.

```
for (e = 0; e < d && *a; e++) {
    val = (int)*(a + e);
    printf("%d ", ((val - 96) * 2 - 13));
}
```

With that change and if you remove the additional `printf("-185\n");` in your code, then it looks correct :

```
Enter the length of the string:
13
Enter the string:
hello world
Outputed hash-code:
-185 3 -3 11 11 17 -141 33 17 23 11 -5 -185
```

And FYI, it is better to not cast the return from `malloc()` :

```
char *a = malloc(sizeof(char) * d);
```

Comment: All of what you said make sense except for adding e to a. When i do that I get an error because you cant make an integer from a pointer.

Comment: I added my for-loop to the answer, you are probably missing the parens.

Comment: Glad to have helped, feel free to accept this answer if it has answered all your questions.

Comment: Note that for *any* pointer or array `a` and index `e`, the expression `*(a + e)` is *exactly* equal to `a[e]`. The latter is usually preferred as it's easier to read and understand.